# Combine SQL Server IIF function and the Count function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I developed an E-Mailing service and there is a form which must show all Emails related to a person in a grid.

I have the SQL query to display the result like this:

```
SELECT
    FOLDERNAME,
    MAILFROM,
    MAILTO,
    LEFT(SUBJ, 200) + IIF(LEN(SUBJECT) > 200, '...', '')
        AS 'Subject',
    CAST(CNT AS VARCHAR(300)) + IIF(LEN(CNT) > 300, '...', '')
        AS 'Content',
    STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(MAILTIMESTAMP, 5, 0, '-'), 8, 0, '-'), 11, 0, ' '), 14, 0, ':')
        AS 'Date - Time',
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ATTACHMENTS WHERE MESSAGEID = MESSAGES.MESSAGEID)
        AS Attachments
FROM
    MESSAGES, FOLDERS
WHERE
    FOLDERS.FOLDERID = MESSAGES.FOLDERID AND
    MESSAGES.PKEY = '4070486';
```

PKEY is the Person Key and Attachments is the number of attachments exists in database as BLOB.

The problem is that I cannot combine IIF function and Count function in the inner Select statement to display the Attachments like this:

```
SELECT IIF(COUNT(*) > 1, 'Yes', 'No')
FROM ATTACHMENTS WHERE MESSAGEID = MESSAGES.MESSAGEID
```

Note that every Email has one XML Attachment and if there are more than one attachment, it should write Yes otherwise No.

I have tried other things like WHERE EXISTS or IIF((SELECT...) > 1,...) and was not successful.

I think there should be a better solution for that.

Comment: Maybe IIF? No IFF function.

Comment: This question has nothing at all to do with Delphi. The fact you display the results in a DBGrid is irrelevant - it wouldn't be any different if you displayed it in SSMS, and it's not Delphi's COUNT() function; that function is part of SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried replacing your IIF(...) with a CASE statement like this ?

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN COUNT(*) <= 1 THEN 'No'
        ELSE 'Yes'
    END AS HAVE_MULTIPLE_VALUES
FROM ATTACHMENTS
WHERE MESSAGEID = MESSAGES.MESSAGEID
```

Comment: That's exactly what I expected and worked for me. U saved my time. Tnx.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    FOLDERNAME,
    MAILFROM,
    MAILTO,
    LEFT(SUBJ, 200) + IIF(LEN(SUBJECT) > 200, '...', '')
        AS 'Subject',
    CAST(CNT AS VARCHAR(300)) + IIF(LEN(CNT) > 300, '...', '')
        AS 'Content',
    STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(MAILTIMESTAMP, 5, 0, '-'), 8, 0, '-'), 11, 0, ' '), 14, 0, ':')
        AS 'Date - Time',
    ATT.N AS Attachments
FROM
    MESSAGES, FOLDERS
LEFT JOIN (SELECT MESSAGEID, COUNT(*) as N FROM ATTACHMENTS GROUP BY MESSAGEID) ATT on ATT.MESSAGEID = MESSAGES.MESSAGEID    
WHERE
    FOLDERS.FOLDERID = MESSAGES.FOLDERID AND
    MESSAGES.PKEY = '4070486';
```